# how to parse the Response as JSON in java

Tags: java, json, http, httpclient

I use the following code to post :

```
try {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            PostMethod method = new PostMethod(VERIFY_PAYMENT_ACTIONURL);

            // key is the parameter
            // MERCHANT_KEY is the value
            method.addParameter("form", "2");
            method.addParameter("key", MERCHANT_KEY.trim());
            method.addParameter("command", VERIFY_PAYMENT_COMMAND.trim());
            method.addParameter("hash", hash);
            method.addParameter("var1", transactionID.trim());
            method.addParameter("salt", ALGORIHTM_SHA512_SALT_KEY.trim());

            int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);

            if (statusCode != -1) {
                in = method.getResponseBodyAsStream();
            }


            String text = method.getResponseBodyAsString();


            System.out.println("text : "+text);

            method.releaseConnection();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and I get the response text as follows :

```
a:3:{s:6:"status";i:1;s:3:"msg";s:44:"1 out of 1 Transactions Fetched Successfully";s:19:"transaction_details";a:1:{i:2298597;a:15:{s:8:"mihpayid";s:18:"403993715508098532";s:10:"request_id";N;s:12:"bank_ref_num";N;s:3:"amt";s:5:"53.77";s:4:"disc";s:4:"0.00";s:4:"mode";s:2:"CC";s:7:"PG_TYPE";s:4:"AXIS";s:7:"card_no";s:16:"512345XXXXXX2346";s:12:"name_on_card";s:3:"emu";s:4:"udf2";s:1:"0";s:7:"addedon";s:19:"2013-06-03 17:34:42";s:6:"status";s:7:"failure";s:14:"unmappedstatus";s:6:"failed";s:12:"Merchant_UTR";N;s:10:"Settled_At";N;}}}
```

now I want to extract the  above output and put it into map like "transactionid" and other details like the following format

```
array('status' => '1',
'msg' => 'Transaction Fetched Successfully',
'transaction_details' =>
array(
'mihpayid' => Transaction ID,
'request_id' => Request ID,
'bank_ref_num' => Bank Reference Number,
'amt' => Amount
'disc' => Discount
'mode' => Transaction Mode (NB for Netbanking, CC for credit card, DC for Debit card, "-" for
'status' => Transaction Status

unknown)
)
);
```

I really do not find any common way to extract the above output. will some one help to do this?

or is it possible for me to convert the above to `JSON` and put them in to a map like the above?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't recognise it but are you sure it's not a well know format?

To turn it into JSON you'd need to 
1)remove every instance of a character that is followed by a colon (and the colon)
2)replace every other semi-colons with a comma
3)replace all the other semi-colons with colons
And you'd need to do all that while taking into account that strings could contain any of those things.

**From comments:**
The string is in PHP serialised form.  This library parses it: https://code.google.com/p/serialized-php-parser/

Comment: it is `PHP serialized string`. had a discussion with the provider +1 for your effort

Comment: Ah, well this library will parse PHP serialised form: https://code.google.com/p/serialized-php-parser/